# Vue: not responding to commands

Tags: vue.js, npm

I installed vue using

```
npm install vue
```

But the terminal wasn't recognizing "vue" command (like vue --version), so I hitted:

```
npm install -g vue-cli@2.7.0
```

And now it says I have version 2.7.0 when I check the version, but it doens't respond neither shows any error when I try:

```
vue ui
```

It just doesn't run. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is no longer the name of the Vue CLI package. You will need to install from @vue/cli as detailed here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed the instructions on this page and it works now.